# Memory issues (my concerns about my app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Under ARC, I know that objects are deallocated automatically by the compiler, but I don't know when exactly it happens.

Consider an object that holds various data in it, like very long `NSStrings` `UIImages` and more. I'm using same object in many of my controllers, but if I pass this object through many controllers via `UINavigationController`, is it still one object or copy itself? I'm concerned that objects won't be `deallocated` because my `controllers` are still on the navigation stack. I really want to figure out what's happening at compiler side.

Comment: Have you read [Apple's guide to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)? (Sorry the link is in Swift; I couldn't find the Objective C equivalent.)

Comment: Most of it, yes I tried to figure it out. @DanielGibbs

Comment: It is pretty simple - a reference count is kept.  When the reference count is 0 then the object is deallocated.  While ever there is a strong reference to an object it will still be in memory - in the case of a navigation controller this means that objects that are on the stack and the objects that those objects hold a strong reference to will be in memory.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: For ARC, when compiling your code, the compile generates retain release for you, it just like what you do with Non-ARC, but compiler do better and ensure there is no misused.

Comment: So if I give attirutes to my object strong that means object has high priority and won't be deallocated in my navigation lifecycle? What do you suggest about memory issue in a application? Like don't use huge objets? Thanks for explanation by the way @Paulw11

Comment: It isn't about "priority".  A strong reference is counted, a weak reference isn't.  If you have a large object that you no longer require then you can simply set the reference to nil and the object will be released if the reference count is now 0.  You can also use separate auto release pools if you have specific requirements.  You should write your app first and then analyse its memory use - then take action if you have a problem.  Unless you are manipulating large video files or hundreds/thousands of images it  typically isn't an issue